# Which is the best way to move cell values to column based on rows in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having values in Excel sheet in the following format:

| code | Warehouse | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A5 | G1 | 3 |
| A2 | G1 | 4 |
| A2 | G2 | 60 |
| A3 | G2 | 20 |

How can I move the quantities from the above rows to warehouse columns like this

| code | G1 | G2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A5 | 3 | 0 |
| A2 | 4 | 60 |
| A3 | 0 | 20 |

[image: Excelshot]

Comment: You are describing a [pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSnxh.png)

Comment: @JvdV Got it. Thank You. Could you tell me how did you manage to get zero in those fields where there are no entries?

Comment: Right click the Pivot table > *Pivottable Options* menu > *Layout & Format* tab > *For empty cells show* field